# How to use avg with where condition in the sql?

Tags: sql, average, where-clause

I want to select products which is higher than the average price.
Here is my SQL:
SELECT ProductName, Price FROM Products
where Price >= AVG(Price);

It said the avg is wrong... any one can help me?

Here is my db:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it:

```sql
SELECT ProductName, Price
FROM Products
where Price >= (select avg(price) from Products)
```

Comment: I think this was first, so I'm upvoting it.

Comment: Appreciate the helper.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below -

```
SELECT ProductName,Price FROM Products
where price>=(select avg(price) from products)
```

Comment: you should consider the performance as well , having group by should be better I think

Comment: @ETL_Devs . . . This might be the most efficient way to express the query.

Answer (score 0):

Simply, use window function.

```
Select * from
(SELECT t.*
       Avg(price) over () as avg_price
  FROM Products t) t
 Where price >= avg_price
```