# SQL Average height of building

Tags: sql

I have a database with buildings, with their names and heights. I want a query that gives me the names of the buildigs that differ less than 100 meters height from the average of all
building.

I have tried:

```
SELECT Name FROM building 
WHERE Height BETWEEN ABS((AVG(Height)) - 100) AND ABS(AVG(Height))
```

But it is not working, any ideas? :)

Comment: No need for ABS, there are no negative height mountains.

Comment: I like the idea to use ABS to catch both smaller and higher heights (see my answer). The issue is the missing subquery, not the usage of ABS.

Comment: @JonasMetzler, I _think_ several dbms'es will have problems optimizing the ABS version, i.e. not using a height index.

Comment: I think this single table "building" or "montain" doesn't make the impression of containing such a high amount of rows that this will be a noticeable issue. But of course, I generally agree ABS can lead to a bad performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a subquery to get the average mountain height:

```
SELECT Name FROM mountain 
WHERE (select AVG(Height) from mountain) BETWEEN Height - 100 and Height + 100
```

Answer (score 1):

`avg` needs to be used in select, not in where

See [How to use avg with where condition in the sql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65335657/how-to-use-avg-with-where-condition-in-the-sql)

So, basically;

```
SELECT Name FROM mountain 
WHERE Height BETWEEN ( select ABS((AVG(Height)) from mountain) - 100) AND (select ABS(AVG(Height)) from mountain)
```

Comment: This gives me syntax error :/

Comment: `selet` should be `select`.

Comment: No need to select the average two times.

Answer (score 1):

You may try using window function as the following:

```
SELECT name, height
FROM
(
  SELECT *,
   AVG(height) OVER () av
  FROM table_name
) T
WHERE ABS(height-av) <= 100
```

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/vbVWv3Ay) on SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your `ABS` idea, you can do this:

```
SELECT name FROM building
WHERE ABS((SELECT AVG(Height) FROM building) - HEIGHT) < 100;
```

You just need to put in a subquery.

Note: It should be mentioned this can be slow if your table has an extremely high amount of rows. In this case, using `BETWEEN` should be prefered.